# What does bindToController do in AngularJS 1.4

Tags: angularjs

What does `bindToController` do in AngularJS 1.4?

Does it change the behaviour so that the controller is looked at for functions rather than the scope?

Comment: Drop *"angular bindToController"* into google and you will get no end of detailed explanations ... including the $compile docs where the official description lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controllerAs` was introduced in Angular 1.3, and enabled the use of `this` in controllers to refer to scope properties.

This was an attempt to reduce use of the scope, and decouple code from the DOM structure.

But it introduced a complexity with two-way data binding (watches). Adding watches with the controller-as syntax still required manipulation of the scope object.

`bindToController`, introduced in Angular 1.4 attempts to solve this issue by using the controller instead of the scope for exposing properties that would normally reside on the scope.